# Pruning urls from git commits

Tags: git, bash

Since git hub has no ability to turn off the automatic url links in commit messages, I'm wanting a way to remove/prune the file "." from the url commit messages.

```
http://www.somesite.com/ -> "http://www.somesite com/"
http://somesite.co.uk/ ->  "http://somesite.co uk/"
http://somesite.eu/ ->  "http://somesite eu/"
http://somesite.eu:8080/ ->  "http://somesite eu:8080/"
etc
```

This is my very basic commit script  ./script.sh ""

```
#!/bin/bash
git pull origin master
git commit -a -m "$1"
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For replacing the dot you mentioned with space do

```
#!/bin/bash
git pull origin master
git commit -a -m "$(echo "$1" | sed "s!\.\([^./]*\(/\|$\)\)! \1!")"
git push origin master
```

For just inserting a space before that same dot do

```
#!/bin/bash
git pull origin master
git commit -a -m "$(echo "$1" | sed "s|\.[^./]*\(/\|$\)| \0|")"
git push origin master
```

Comment: That looks great (used the top suggestion). If you drop the "/" at the end of the url. "http://somesite.com" it seems to parse the url, Anyway around that?

Comment: Surprised I'm not the only one who has issues with url parsing in github. I wish it could be turned off.

Comment: Ah, right updated the answer. What is the problem with the URL parsing, what is bad with it?

Comment: So? The more referrers, the better the google rank possibly. :-)